# BlackBerry 10 development toolkit

Tags: android, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, android-2.2-froyo

I am confused how to start BlackBerry 10 development. I followed [this](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/install_plugin_prerequisites_1895476_11.html) to start with a simple project to get to know BlackBerry 10 development. I have everything in place that is said on the page. What project am I supposed to select when starting development;

1. Java project
2. Android project
3. Other...

Please guide with useful links to BlackBerry 10 development.

Comment: You have clearly already programmed in cascades, and now you're asking how to start again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide is about environment for porting existing Android applications to the BB10 platform. If you want to start BB development from scratch you can follow [this guide](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/getting_started/index.html)